# PCB Trace Impedance Matching on microcontroller

Tags: pcb, antenna, wifi, pcb-antenna

I'm doing research for the best antenna for a 2.4 GHz connection from our device to a local router. The problem is that our device will have varying loads connected to the other pins of the micro controller.

My question is will the varying loads on other pins of a micro controller will effect the impedance matching for the antenna?

I have tried searching this with no avail. I have no experience with antennas so pardon if this is a trivial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each pin on a MCU has an individual driver. If one pin drives a matching antenna network, any other pins are driving something else independently. Of course this assumes that the power rail for the MCU is solidly driven by power supply and properly bypassed, so any cross-talk over (presumably) common power rail is minimized. But varying loads on other pin shouldn't have any effect on impedance matching.

The only bad case could be if the antenna driver has its impedance control via some analog circuitry set by a bias resistor, all derived from the same power rail as the antenna driver itself. Then any rail ripples will change the driver impedance proportionally to ripple amplitude.

Answer (score 2):

No, it should not have any influence, to my knowledge. Output impedance (that your antenna has to match) is a property of the power output stage inside the microcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Your MCU has internal rails/busses for VDD and GND. As output drivers go through HI or LO to TRISTATE/OFF, the impedance of the GND and VDD rails will indeed change. Thus the GND (likely also the Substrate of the silicon) will experience varying impedance to GND of the PCB.

Will this be a problem? Get a Network Analyzer and characterize the RF pin.

Or drive that pin with a 0.1 volt square wave with 1nanoSecond edge, and examine how the edge undershoot/overshoot changes as the MCU program runs through its various tasks.